# I want to read excel and map columns to database columns or save the metadata of excel into database

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot

If user upload similar excel with same headers I have to automatically read them based on the saved metadata. The technology stack is java, spring and mysql

I had designed database to store hearders and row numbers of the excel. I want know weather i am going in right path

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The framework you are probably looking for is Spring Batch. It can read a CSV file (Excel can save files in this format). Even very long files - they will be read in chunks. For the read data you can implement an optional processor class. For example to change the format or enhance it with data from a database. After doing it you can write out the rows - again in chunks. You can do it in a variety of formats like flat file, database, message queue etc.